# No module "psutil" in MSYS2 how can i fix this problem

Tags: libraries, msys2

I am trying to run python code in the MSYS2 Shell.

I was not able to download GTK into my SPYDer environment so i was recommended to use MSYS2. However when trying to run the code it is telling me no 'psutil module found' which i have installed already

I tried reinstalling the library into my windows environment but the problem still persists.

Comment: What code are you running?

Comment: Which of the three MSYS2 shells are you using?  What command are you using to run your code, and what is the output of `which python` and `which python3`?  How exactly did you install psutil?

Comment: I am trying to build a cpu/gpu/temp monitor for a project on SPYder. I installed psutil through pip install.  First i tried to run my code on SPYder but it says not GTK3 library found. So instead i moved my .py files over to my MSYS2 folder and tried running it from there which is where i got the pstuil module not found. I tried in both MSYS2 and MSYS64